# Ubuntu 18.04 booting in console mode even after reinstalling drivers

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, gdm

So basically I just did one thing (or one mistake I would say): **apt-removing python2 and python3** since I wanted to reinstall it for other reasons.

During the process I think it may removed something "extra" and after rebooting I'm stuck with the Ubuntu console mode.

I've already tried (more than once) to completely uninstall nvidia-drivers and reinstall them with no success.

I see that they are there but I'm still in console mode. I've also checked grub options during booting and I don't see anything relevant apart from quit splash that should be harmless(to my knowledge).

Thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE, here's the `grep -E "remove|purge" /var/log/dpkg.log` output:

[PasteBin log](https://pastebin.com/3s4ABW32)

Comment: python3 is essential, the system can't work without it. removing it is fatal to the system. Please try `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing -y && sudo apt install -f -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` and see if it restores it.

Comment: I tryed, still nothing...

Comment: Did it fix and update or you got errors? Were you connected to Internet? Please describe the output

Comment: It correctly upgraded everything with no errors but rebooting still gets me in console mode.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` then run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` then reboot

Comment: As I said I've already tryed that. Tryed again but with no success. Running 'prime-select query' displays that nvidia card is being used.

Comment: what is the output of `sudo systemctl status gdm`

Comment: Unit gdm.service could not be found. I'll also add that console is telling me after booting that "/usr/share/..../virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh" no such file or directory.

Comment: try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: This worked!!!! I wonder now what actually went wrong :\

Comment: Well done : ) Please [edit] your question and add the output of `grep -E "remove|purge" /var/log/dpkg.log` to investigate what went wrong.

Comment: Will do ASAP. Thanks anyway! How can I add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Answer added. Please update your question to list the output of `sudo systemctl status gdm` so that it helps people diagnose the problem. I will also update my answer later when you add the output of `grep -E "remove|purge" /var/log/dpkg.log` to indicate the cause.

Comment: Sorry I'm late. I added a paste link with the full output. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `sudo systemctl status gdm`:

> **Unit gdm.service could not be found.**

Suggests that `gdm3` the graphical login manager is missing ( probably removed by mistake ).

Installing `ubuntu-desktop` like so:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

or if it the above tells you `ubuntu-desktop` is already installed, try reinstalling it like so:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Should solve this problem.

---

As to what caused this, the answer is in your `grep -E "remove|purge" /var/log/dpkg.log` output:

```
2020-04-10 19:24:11 remove ubuntu-desktop:amd64 1.417.4
2020-04-10 19:24:27 remove gdm3:amd64 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4
```

`ubuntu-desktop` the Ubuntu desktop environment and `gdm3` the graphical login manager which is part of `ubuntu-desktop` were **removed** along with many other packages.

The reason they were removed although you might have not removed them in particular is one of two reasons:

- You tried to remove or install a package while you have not ran `sudo apt update` in a long time and you did not pay attention to **APT** prompting you to accept the removal of packages and you just typed yes and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Yes you don't only need **update** to install, but you also need it to correctly remove packages.
- They were removed as a parts of another package you tried to remove and again you did not pay attention to **APT** prompting you to accept the removal of packages and you just typed yes and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Best of luck.