# Lost my desktop gui

Tags: command-line, files

I am new to linux, played around and did something bad, that after reboot I can only use cli - terminal.

Now I can easily just install a new version of Ubuntu, but I need few files from my desktop, it is vital. How do I transfer them to my USB stick using only cli? I hope it's possible...

Comment: Try `startx`, and if that gives an error, `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and then `startx` again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 booting in console mode even after reinstalling drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225988/ubuntu-18-04-booting-in-console-mode-even-after-reinstalling-drivers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between console and GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui)