# Ubuntu boots to black screen after trying to install ibus dependencies

Tags: 16.04, reboot

I tried editing in GRUB and changing `quiet splash` to `nomodeset`, and all it did was turn the black screen purple. I'm not sure what to do. I was trying to install dependencies for ibus for a Tibetan keyboard. Then I tried to restart and the black screen began.

I installed the dependencies listed here: 
https://www.christian-steinert.de/home/tibetan-computing/typing-tibetan-on-windows-and-linux

Comment: Can you login-in in the black/purple screen? do you see a login prompt where you can enter your username and password?

Comment: @Raffa Nope, it's only a black screen. I can click ctrl-alt-del and be brought back to the GRUB menu though. That's about it.

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA graphics card?

Comment: @Raffa No, I have an Intel one.

Comment: OK, You need to go to recovery mode and enable networking then drop to a root shell then mount your system in read and write mode then install ubuntu desktop like so `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163539/968501) should give you an idea on how to do that.

Comment: @Raffa Okay so I did everything in the first link. After rebooting, I started Ubuntu and got a prompt for my username and password on black screen.

Comment: Please do `sudo apt update` before you attempt to install anything and pay attention to when APT tells you it will remove packages. Do not answer yes to removing packages unless you know what you are doing. You can also attempt to do other fixes from the recovery mode like editing GRUB and removing `nomodeset` back to `quiet splash` or uninstalling the lately installed packages that caused the problem.

Comment: Please enter your username and password then run `systemctl status gdm*` and `systemctl status lightdm*`what output do you get?

Comment: @Raffa Actually, putting in the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` worked for me. Sorry I misread your comment. After doing what's in the first link you commented and running that command, I am now able to fully boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 booting in console mode even after reinstalling drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225988/ubuntu-18-04-booting-in-console-mode-even-after-reinstalling-drivers)

Comment: Well done : ). Be careful next time you install something.

Answer (score 1):

After doing what's in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164480/ubuntu-19-04-problems-install-upgrades/1164505#1164505), and then putting in the login prompt `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`, I was able to fully boot and load into Ubuntu.