# problem with ubuntu booting

Tags: 20.04, login, lightdm, bootloader, gdm

I guess I ran some command trying to install something. After that, when I tried to restart my PC, it showed

```
error while reading block run fsck manually
```

which I did. After that, it was stuck in blackscreen with blinking cursor. So I installed `gdm3` after login after I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Now it is stuck in a login loop.

I also installed `lightdm` and checked permission of `xauthority` file and `/tmp` file. All are fine. Also tried creating own `xauthority` but still it's in login loop.
When I run a command to check which desktop manager is installed, at the end it shows

```
gkr-pam unable to locate daemon control file
```

I also ran `startx`
I guess I ran

```
sudo add-apt-repository "*deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install adobereader-enu*
```

These commands after which, all problem started.

Comment: please with solution also explain how and why the problem started

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 booting in console mode even after reinstalling drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225988/ubuntu-18-04-booting-in-console-mode-even-after-reinstalling-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

When I rarely have a linux or Windows computer that won't boot I pull out my Boot Repair CD. It is downloadable in ISO format to be burned to CD. Then you boot from it. It fixes the boot software automatically. (I use Linux Mint. I used Boot Repair a couple of weeks ago. I don't remember what caused the boot error. It fixed the boot process.)